# unpacking data using a fortran code

Tags: fortran

i'm a grad student trying to work with atmospheric data files provided by NOAA. I have a code that reads the data but only writes the first four columns of data. I know that the subroutine at the end of the code unpacks the data. I was thinking maybe if I take out the conditional statements then it might write the entire data. But that doesn't work. I need to develop this code so that it writes the entire data file and not just the first four elements. Any help is appreciated. The code is shown below:

```
    PROGRAM CHK_DATA

    !-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! Simple program to dump the first few elements of the data array for each
    ! record of an ARL packed meteorological file. Used for diagnostic testing.
    ! Created: 23 Nov 1999 (RRD)
    !          14 Dec 2000 (RRD) - fortran90 upgrade
    !          18 Oct 2001 (RRD) - expanded grid domain
    !          03 Jun 2008 (RRD) - embedded blanks
    !-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      REAL,          ALLOCATABLE :: RDATA(:,:)   
      CHARACTER(1),  ALLOCATABLE :: CPACK(:)

      CHARACTER(4)               :: KVAR, MODEL 
      CHARACTER(50)              :: LABEL          
      CHARACTER(80)              :: FDIR, FILE
      CHARACTER(3072)            :: HEADER
      LOGICAL                    :: FTEST

    !-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      INTERFACE
      SUBROUTINE UNPACK(CPACK,RDATA,NX,NY,NEXP,VAR1)
      CHARACTER(1),INTENT(IN)  :: CPACK(:)  
      REAL,        INTENT(OUT) :: RDATA(:,:)   
      INTEGER,     INTENT(IN)  :: NX,NY,NEXP
      REAL,        INTENT(IN)  :: VAR1
      END SUBROUTINE
      END INTERFACE
    !-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ! directory and file name
      WRITE(*,*)'Enter directory name:'
      READ(*,'(a)')FDIR
      FDIR=ADJUSTL(FDIR)
      WRITE(*,*)'Enter file name:'
      READ(*,'(a)')FILE
      FILE=ADJUSTL(FILE)

    ! test for meteo file existence
      KLEN=LEN_TRIM(FDIR)
      INQUIRE(FILE=FDIR(1:KLEN)//FILE,EXIST=FTEST)
      IF(.NOT.FTEST)THEN
         WRITE(*,*)'Unable to find file: ',FILE
         WRITE(*,*)'On local directory : ',FDIR(1:KLEN)
         STOP
      END IF

    ! open file to decode the standard label (50) plus the
    ! fixed portion (108) of the extended header
      OPEN(10,FILE=FDIR(1:KLEN)//FILE,RECL=158,ACCESS='DIRECT',FORM='UNFORMATTED')

    ! decode the standard portion of the index record
      READ(10,REC=1)LABEL,HEADER(1:108)
      READ(LABEL,'(5I2,4X,A4)')IYR,IMO,IDA,IHR,IFC,KVAR
      WRITE(*,'(A,4I5)')'Opened file       : ',IYR,IMO,IDA,IHR

      IF(KVAR.NE.'INDX')THEN
         WRITE(*,*)'WARNING Old format meteo data grid'
         WRITE(*,*)LABEL
         WRITE(*,*)HEADER(1:108)
         STOP
      END IF

    ! decode extended portion of the header
      READ(HEADER(1:108),'(A4,I3,I2,12F7.0,3I3,I2,I4)',ERR=900)                    &
             MODEL,    ICX,       MN,                                              &
             POLE_LAT, POLE_LON,  REF_LAT,                                         &
             REF_LON,  SIZE,      ORIENT,                                          &
             TANG_LAT, SYNC_XP,   SYNC_YP,                                         &
             SYNC_LAT, SYNC_LON,  DUMMY,                                           &
             NX,       NY,        NZ,                                              &
             K_FLAG,   LENH

    ! close file and reopen with proper length
      CLOSE (10)
      NXY = NX*NY
      LEN = NXY+50
      OPEN(10,FILE=FDIR(1:KLEN)//FILE,RECL=LEN,ACCESS='DIRECT',FORM='UNFORMATTED')

    ! print file diagnostic
      WRITE(*,'(A,4I5)')'Grid size and lrec: ',NX,NY,NXY,LEN
      WRITE(*,'(A,I5)') 'Header record size: ',LENH

    ! allocate array space
      ALLOCATE (RDATA(NX,NY), STAT=KRET)   
      ALLOCATE (CPACK(NXY),   STAT=KRET)

    ! read entire file and print headers
      KREC=1
    100 READ(10,REC=KREC,ERR=800)LABEL,(CPACK(K),K=1,NXY)
        READ(LABEL,'(6I2,2X,A4,I4,2E14.7)',ERR=900) IY,IM,ID,IH,IF,KL,  &
                                                 KVAR,NEXP,PREC,VAR1

        WRITE(*,'(A)')LABEL
        IF(KVAR.NE.'INDX') CALL UNPACK(CPACK,RDATA,NX,NY,NEXP,VAR1)

        READ(*,*,END=800)
        KREC=KREC+1
      GO TO 100

    800 STOP

    900 WRITE(*,*)'ERROR: decoding header'
        WRITE(*,*)LABEL
        WRITE(*,*)HEADER(1:108)

    END PROGRAM chk_data

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SUBROUTINE UNPACK(CPACK,RDATA,NX,NY,NEXP,VAR1)

  CHARACTER(1),INTENT(IN)  :: CPACK(:)  
  REAL,        INTENT(OUT) :: RDATA(:,:)   
  INTEGER,     INTENT(IN)  :: NX,NY,NEXP
  REAL,        INTENT(IN)  :: VAR1

! only required when dealing with F95 compilers
! replace ICHAR below with internally defined JCHAR function
! CHARACTER MYCHR*1
! JCHAR(MYCHR)=IAND(ICHAR(MYCHR),255)

  SCALE=2.0**(7-NEXP)
  VOLD=VAR1
  INDX=0
  DO J=1,NY
     DO I=1,NX
        INDX=INDX+1
        RDATA(I,J)=(ICHAR(CPACK(INDX))-127.)/SCALE+VOLD
        VOLD=RDATA(I,J)
        IF(I.LE.2.AND.J.LE.2)  &
           WRITE(*,'(3I5,E12.4)')J,I,ICHAR(CPACK(INDX)),RDATA(I,J)
        IF(I.GE.(NX-1).AND.J.GE.(NY-1))  &
           WRITE(*,'(3I5,E12.4)')J,I,ICHAR(CPACK(INDX)),RDATA(I,J)
     END DO
     VOLD=RDATA(1,J)
  END DO

END SUBROUTINE unpack
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice the comment

```
! only required when dealing with F95 compilers
! replace ICHAR below with internally defined JCHAR function
! CHARACTER MYCHR*1
! JCHAR(MYCHR)=IAND(ICHAR(MYCHR),255)
```

Try to uncomment the definition, and change the calls to `CHAR` to calls to `JCHAR`.

`ICHAR` is an intrinsic function in Fortran that behaves different, than the code expects. It all seems suspicious, because the `JCHAR` does nothing to numbers below 256.

For further porting consider using `IMPLICIT NONE` and modules.

**---EDIT --**-

Now I see your conditionals.  If you remove

IF(I.LE.2.AND.J.LE.2)  &

and

IF(I.GE.(NX-1).AND.J.GE.(NY-1))  &

what exactly does the code do? We do not have the data.

(I know, there are a lot of the data files on the page you downloaded your program, but I am not going to the all the work for you, sorry.)

Cant you find a complete code to work with the data anywhere?

Comment: The data is in grid format. so the conditional statements only print the values of I and J tht are in grids 2 and below. I've searched and I havent beeen able to find a complete code to unpack this data. Also, I uncommented to definition of JCHAR and i got a few errors.            Error: Type mismatch in argument 'mychr' at (1); passed CHARACTER(1) to INTEGER(4)
chk_data.f90:142.32:

WRITE(*,'(3I5,E12.4)')J,I,JCHAR(CPACK(INDX)),RDATA(I,J)

Comment: You probably didn't uncomment the line above it. You should really use IMPLICIT NONE.